# Active screen centered DIV from iframe using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a lengthy page (say 2500px) which is having links on it. When I click any link I open a screen centered DIV (using jQuery window height, scrollposition etc - code added below).

Its working fine when I browse the page using browser directly but when I include this page (especially in WordPress) in any other page using iframe then screen centered div code do not work as per expectations and shows the popup according to the height of iframe. I mean it takes complete iframe as active window.

How can I fix this? I mean I want to show screen centered DIV even if link is clicked from iframe.

NOTE: Parent and child pages are on different domains. 
Parent = Page that is having iframe that will have my page as source
Child = My page

Here is the screen centered code which I am using

```
$("#myDiv").css("position","absolute");
$("#myDiv").css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window).height() - $("#myDiv").outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window).scrollTop()) + "px");
$("#myDiv").css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window).width() - $("#myDiv").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window).scrollLeft()) + "px");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More or less copypasted from 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage

You transfer your variables from one window

```
otherWindow.postMessage(message, targetOrigin, [transfer]);
```

to the other.

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {   
    if (event.origin !== "http://example.org:8080"){
       return;
    }else{
       // get data from the event and update it
    }
```

It's a little bit like dispatching events, just that you have to check the origin very strictly as *anyone* can send messages.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#myDiv").css("position","absolute");
$("#myDiv").css("top", Math.max(0, (($(window.parent).height() - $("#myDiv").outerHeight()) / 2) + $(window.parent).scrollTop()) + "px");
$("#myDiv").css("left", Math.max(0, (($(window.parent).width() - $("#myDiv").outerWidth()) / 2) + $(window.parent).scrollLeft()) + "px");
```

EXPLANATION: You use the context of `window.parent` to find and modify the css properties.

Comment: Crossing the iframe boundary across domains raises a security error. You need to pass messages.

Comment: @TIMINeutron
Your code will work well if both parent and child on same domain but if domains are different. Your code will not work

Comment: @Winchestro Can you please explain how? If you are having any example (URL)?